# Change default URL from /web/guest

Tags: liferay-6

How to change the liferay url  from  `/web/guest` to another. In my Liferay Control Panel Communities (in Portal) the option is not there (it is not visible)

Comment: What version of liferay are you using?

Comment: Read [this](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4233941)

Comment: Sir How to Create communities in liferay

Answer (score 1):

Add/Change the below property in your portal-ext.properties

```
#
# This sets the default home URL of the portal.
#
company.default.home.url=/web/guest
```